# ListView items background issue

Tags: android, listview

I'm having problems with ListView items. I'm using listSelector for it.
I need item changes background while pressed. But when i press on it, all items change backgrounds. It occures on Android 2.3.6. At 4.0.3 and more it works well.

ListSelector

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:id="@+id/defaultSelector">
<item android:drawable="@color/defaultDashboardItemBackground" android:state_enabled="false" android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="false"/>
<item android:drawable="@color/defaultDashboardItemHover" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@color/defaultDashboardItemBackground" android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="false"/>
```

Some code

```
ListView list = (ListView) act.findViewById(R.id.menu_listview);
list.setBackgroundColor(act.getResources().getColor(getThemeBackground(theme)));
list.setSelector(act.getResources().getDrawable( getThemeSelector(theme)));
list.addHeaderView(createHeader("HEADER"));
list.setAdapter(adap);
```

Answer (score 1):

this worked for me

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/playList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:listSelector="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
    >

</ListView>
```

in the event onItemClickListener add

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            parent.setSelection(position);
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Set this attribute to your listview`android:cacheColorHint="@null"`
This may help fix it.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
    android:listSelector="#00000000"
    android:fadingEdge="none"/>
```

And don't define background color in ListView.
Define background color(Selector) or Image(Selector) in listitem.xml root layout.

Hope this will help you.